# High resolution canvas page scale to window height

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I try to create 2 layers of hight resolution (2480x3508) canvas elements scale to 100% window height and 50% window width.

Currently, I have 2 canvas layers. But if I set a high resolution (2480x3508)  layers are much larger than a screen.

It is my code:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 1235px; height: 100%;">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="2480" height="3500" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="2480" height="3500" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

So in summarize:
I want to get 2 canvas layers one on the another.
The canvas layers must be in high resolution.
And the canvas layers must be scaled to width: 1235px; height: 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use height=100% and also width=100%